# Changing Android Project build target renders older API emulators unusable

Tags: android, eclipse, api, compatibility

I am writing an application that uses

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

and I first started to write it with Project build target = 2.3.3
Now I'm changing Project build target via Eclipse "properties" and setting it to 4.0. But when I do this, the emulator I used previously (2.3.3) is now unusable (red cross on it in the choice menu). I have not used anything restricted to API 14, and reverting to Project build target 2.3.3 puts things back to normality. I wonder why I cannot use the other emulator? Thank you

Comment: The red cross doesn't mean you can't run it on the emulator, it just means that the API level is lower than your target build... try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the comment as an answer:
The red cross doesn't mean you can't run it on the emulator, it just means that the API level is lower than your target build... try and see for yourself.

**EDIT** Answer for Enigma's question:

Android team suggests you always compile your source using the latest SDK. In order to make sure your app is trying to run API calls it doesn't have you should create conditions in your code like so

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1)
       {Run Honeycomb implementation}
    else 
       {run Gingerbrea/Froyo implementation}
```

Comment: Is it ok to do that? We will be building with Android 3.0 SDK and we run it on, say Android 2.2. So what happens to the APIs that are specific to 3.0? I'm not supposed to make use of those APIs?

Comment: You should use this kind of condition, and if it is used on Android 2.2, make sure you create an implementation that fits it in your else{}.